# Why am I seeing different behavior between 'if' and ternary with linq?

Tags: c#, if-statement, ternary-operator

I have a situation where I was using a ternary operator to determine whether or not an IEnumerable is null, and it was not behaving as I would expect.

If I do this:

```
var children = clickedItem.Children != null ? clickedItem.Children.ToArray() : null;
```

then I receive an argument null exception ("source cannot be null") which indicates that the `.ToArray()` occurred despite the null check.

If I change this to (seemingly) identical logic:

```
var children = clickedItem.Children;
if (children != null) children = children.ToArray();
```

then the error disappears. Does the ternary operator not short-circuit as I always imagined it did?

**EDIT** Per the questions:

Yes, I am setting children the first time in, but not the second:

```
public IEnumerable<AlbumOrTrack> Children
 {
    get
    {
        if (_children == null)
        {
            _children = _dataAccess.GetChildren(this);
        }
        return _children;
    }
 }
```

And the exception is occurring in the .ToArray() call. I am getting the

```
// Exceptions:
//   System.ArgumentNullException:
//     source is null.
```

(from metadata)

Comment: *Where* are you getting the exception?

Comment: Do you have the implementation of `clickedItem.Children`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One difference is that in the second form you're only evaluating the expression `clickedItem.Children` *once*.

Imagine if the `Children` property were implemented as:

```
public IEnumerable<Child> Children
{
    get
    {
        var ret = children;
        // Mwahahaha! A getter with side-effects. They'll never expect that!
        children = null; 
        return ret;
    }
}
```

(Or it could just be a race condition, of course.)

Comment: ...And you're right. As usual. I do have a race condition, and I need to be using a clone instead of setting _children to null. Thanks!